# How to pop to root view controller with view hierarchy containing multiple Navigation controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view hierarchy with **multiple** **UINavigationControllers**

Now from a particular view controller, I wanted to pop to window.rootviewcontroller

How can I do that?

I tried

[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController popToRootViewController];

But it does not work. Please suggest.

Please note I want to go to window.rootVC.

THis will not work for me

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the window instance and set the root view controller again, as `popToRootViewController` only pops to root view controller of particular navigation stack

```
- (void)popToRoot
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIWindow *mainWindow = appDelegate.window;
    ViewController *viewControllerObj = [ViewController new];
    UINavigationController *navigationObject = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewControllerObj];
    [mainWindow setRootViewController:navigationObject];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

set

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;


[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: It will take to root view controller of current nav controller....I want to go to window.rootviewcontroller