# Popping to root navigation controller - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have multiple navigation controllers. They are placed like this hierarchy :

```
(A)SWRevealViewController
       (B)Navigation Controller(sw_front) 
            (C)HomeViewController (root view controller)
                  (D)TabBarController -->
                            (E)Navigation Controller 1--> 
                                 (F)TableController 1 -->
                                 (F)TableController 2.
                            (E)Navigation Controller 2--> 
                                 (F)TableController 1 -->
                                 (F)TableController 2.
```

I want to pop to the root view controller of the main navigation controllers, i.e, I want to go from F to C or B. I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28426793/7205816) answer, and also converted it to swift as follows :

```
let appdel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let mainwindow : UIWindow = appdel.window!
    let vcObj : HomeViewController = HomeViewController()
    let navObj : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vcObj)
    mainwindow.rootViewController = navObj
```

but it just shows a blank black screen. Please can anyone help.

I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

Comment: let drawerViewController = viewControllerFrom("Main", vcid: "SliderMenuViewController")
            let dashboardVC = viewControllerFrom("Main", vcid: "UserDashboardViewController") as! UserDashboardViewController
            
            let navigationControl = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dashboardVC )
 window?.rootViewController = navigationControl t

Comment: How do you add TabBarController to HomeViewController?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya this doesn't work. There is nothing such as viewControllerFrom()

Comment: @ZaidPathan I added it on the storyboard but accessed it through storyboard ID in code

Comment: @user7205816 But how did you add it? I mean present/push/addChild view?

Comment: I'm leaving now, may be able to answer in next couple of hours, if you do not get answer.

Comment: @ZaidPathan I am accessing it through SWRevealViewController push method as : sw.pushFrontViewController(VC, animated: true)

Comment: Loop through all `presentingViewController` starting with `self.presentingViewController`. Eventually one of them will be the rootNav controller. Call `dismissViewController` on that one it will pop all controllers until that one is shown.

Comment: @Brandon please give me demo code if possible. I don't exactly get your point

Answer (score 6):

Instead of pushing your `tabBarVC` using `sw.pushFrontViewController(VC, animated: true)` try using `navigationController`'s push method,

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBarVC!, animated: true)
```

Then from TableController call following to go to `HomeViewController`,

```
func goToHomeNavVC(){
        //parent is TabBar Controller
        self.parent?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Here is a [Demo](https://github.com/ZaidSA/SOSWDemo)

Comment: If I do .pushViewController then there is space for a navigation bar below the actual navigation bar

Comment: Send your demo project if possible

Comment: That isn't possible as project almost done.. But I need to do SWRevealViewControllerPushSegue for sure through code so I can't even use .pushViewController. Please help

Comment: If you need one-to-one help, contact me. Else I need a demo for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss to a particular view controller by iterating the `presentingViewController` hierarchy and then calling `dismissViewController` on the one you want to dismiss to.

Example:

```
func dismissToHome() {
    var vc = self.presentingViewController

    while (vc != nil) {
        if (vc!.isKind(of: HomeViewController.self)) {
            break
        }

        vc = vc?.presentingViewController
    }

    vc?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        print("Dismissed to: ", vc!)
    })
}
```

The above will call `dismissViewController` on the `HomeViewController` which will dismiss the view controller that it presented. Since that controller is dismissed, all other child controllers are dismissed by their parents.

Comment: @user7205816; I tested this on the same hierarchy that you have. I installed `SWRevealViewController` via CocoaPods. It worked fine on XCode 8.2.1 iOS 8, 9, 10 simulator.

Comment: I have used the SWRevealPushSegue from C to D, maybe that's why it isn't working

Answer (score -2):

I used

```
let modal: UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryBoardID) as UIViewController!
self.present(modal, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to do something like this. StoryBoradID is the identifier you gave the ViewController. Maybe this helps in your case.

Comment: Doing this will keep all of the VC's in the Navigation Controller in memory and allow the user to re-create them on top of themselves. Bad practice.